# How to append an element in a list a declared in global , while list.append() statement is inside a function

Tags: python, global-variables, scope

corrected code for query , both var and result are global variables which are required to be accessed inside a function

```
import copy
result = []
var = 'second list empty'

def permute(arr1,arr2):    
    if(len(arr2) <= 0):
        global result.append(var)
        return
    stx = "".join(arr1)
    for x in arr2:
       var = stx + x
       arr3 = copy.deepcopy(arr2)
       arr3.remove(x)
       permute(var.split(),arr3)
```

Comment: what is `var` ?? you reference it before assignment.

Comment: why are you returning `None` ?

Comment: function need not return anything , it is there to escape recursion , the semicolon was a mistake since i just switched from coding in java to python , i corrected it in the question

Comment: it works after removing the global keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the word `global` from your `append` statement.

You have:

```
global result.append(var)
```

It should be:

```
result.append(var)
```

You only need the `global` keyword when you`re reassigning a global variable inside the function, and you use it *just* to declare the variable global; you can't do anything else with it in that statement.